# Preventing unauthorized access to my custom app

Tags: php, api, authorization

I am making a mobile application, and I have created an API to send JSON data to the app. The thing is if we called the API with `www.domainname.com/example.php?listid=1` this will bring all the list information that has the id of 1. The issue I am having is figuring out how I can prevent an unauthorized user from accessing the API. I want the users to only be able to view the lists that they have created.

I am using PHP

Comment: How do you want to authenticate users?

Comment: i want to authenticate by username and password from the mobile application, as they sign in to the application , and who is signed in can view his data only, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a secure authentication token with all API requests.
(and validate it on the server)

You should probably also use SSL.

Comment: you meeen something like this, www.domain.com/example.php?auth=123kjhbk12j3kj123kjb123kjb13123kjb

Comment: where the auth is encoding of the username and the password??

Comment: No.  Where auth is an expiring nonce generated by the server after a login request.  **Never** keep a raw password.

Comment: so if the user logged in from the mobile app, and then he wants to request the api, so the server has to do the validation.. right? so this step should be done every time any user want to request data from  via api. can you please give me a link or explain in details how i can do the authentication token from the server side?

Comment: It should work just like a normal HTTP login system, but with custom code instead of HTML forms.